# Unable to convince apt to use the PPA version of a package rather than the universe version

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, ppa, repository

I am attempting to use the PPA version of `touchegg` on the Raspberry Pi version of MATE (`focal`; 20.04). The PPA is at `touchegg` version 2.0+ while Ubuntu Universe is at 1.1+.

The PPA info is here: [https://launchpad.net/~touchegg/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+packages](https://launchpad.net/%7Etouchegg/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+packages)

I execute:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:touchegg/stable
```

and the PPA appears to install. This is followed by `apt-get update`.

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/touchegg-ubuntu-stable-focal.list` contains:

```
deb http http://ppa.launchpad.net/touchegg/stable/ubuntu focal main
```

I also placed `99-touchegg-repository` in `/etc/apt/preferences.d` ; it contains the following:

```
Package: touchegg

Pin: release o=LP-PPA-touchegg

Pin-priority: 450
```

However, `apt policy touchegg` still shows that the only version of touchegg available is that in universe. Whenever I `apt install touchegg`, I get the old version from `universe`.

How do I get apt within Ubuntu MATE to use the version of `touchegg` in the PPA?

Comment: also asked at https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/cant-use-ppa-with-mate/24548  (the builds are visible - https://launchpad.net/%7Etouchegg/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+packages)

Comment: You can ask the maintainer to enable PPA builds for ARM. Here's how to. https://askubuntu.com/q/371339/124466

Comment: Also IIRC the default pin priority is 500, so if you use 450, it would be lower priority than packages from universe.

Comment: Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg/issues/522

Answer (score 9):

That PPA only has "amd64" builds, which is a different architecture from RP. You'll need an Intel/AMD computer to use it.

To see what builds are available, click a package to expand it.

Comment: There is an `armhf` package on the [github releases page](https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg/releases).

Answer (score 8):

**Update 20210910**: the mentioned PPA now [has packages](https://launchpad.net/%7Etouchegg/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=focal) for both *armhf* and *arm64*. You can remove pin-file and install them as usual using commands below:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/99-touchegg-repository
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:touchegg/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touchegg
```

Below is historical part of the answer.

---

You are doing all the steps correctly. The problem here is that PPA provides packages only for *amd64* CPU architecture. See [PPA file-listing](http://ppa.launchpad.net/touchegg/stable/ubuntu/pool/main/t/touchegg/) for confirmation.

I wrote a message to “Touchégg” team on launchpad with request for *armhf* and *arm64* package builds. Let's wait for reaction.

If you are in hurry -  [download official packages from GitHub](https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg/releases/tag/2.0.11) by using commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
# for arm64
wget -c https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg/releases/download/2.0.11/touchegg_2.0.11_arm64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./touchegg_2.0.11_arm64.deb

# for armhf
wget -c https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg/releases/download/2.0.11/touchegg_2.0.11_armhf.deb
sudo apt-get install ./touchegg_2.0.11_armhf.deb
```

Or compile this package manually directly on RaspberryPi. At first enable source code (*`deb-src`* repositories) in Software and Updates, then execute commands below:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get build-dep touchegg
sudo apt-get install git build-essential cmake libcairo2-dev libgtk-3-dev libinput-dev libpugixml-dev libudev-dev libxrandr-dev

cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg.git -b  2.0.11
cd touchegg
dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us
sudo apt-get install ../touchegg_2.0.11_arm*.deb
```

Comment: Thanks. That completely makes sense. 

Compiled and the software executes. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to detect any gestures. Time for more debugging.

Comment: @compilebunny if this answer has resolved your question, consider [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @compilebunny If something does not work, you can create a bug report at GitHub. https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg

Comment: This answer is great! Unfortunately, I don't see any checkmarks in the places where https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work says that they are supposed to be. Perhaps I need more "points" in order to be able to "vote"? I'm not too familiar with this system.